# javascript confirm window to get bool value

Tags: javascript, c#-2.0

i have a Page called addtitle.aspx - here i will upload a document which is submitted by a user...

after all i will redirect this page into versions.aspx....

Now my question is...

i need to confirm that user like to preview the document before going to Version.aspx...

Here i ll show a confirm window but i cant predict the values chosen by user either Yes or no..

For ref:
///////////////////////////////

```
 bool sStatus = ShowPopupMessage("You want to preview the document?");

    if(sStatus)
    {
      //Preview event
    }
    else
    {
         response.redirect("");
    }

    private bool ShowPopupMessage(string Message)
    {
      System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
      sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
      sb.Append("return confirm('");
      sb.Append(Message);
      sb.Append("')};");
      sb.Append("</script>");

      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "return confirm", sb.ToString(),true);
    }
```

Is it possible to predict that if the user has chosen "Yes"?

Comment: You would like to __predict__ what the user is going to choose?

Comment: Two months and 11 previous questions. With respect, you really shoudl be formatting code correctly at this point rather than relying on people like @Cybernate to do it for you. Have a look at the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question area, and at [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Comment: I think you need to implement `CrystalBallPredicter`

Comment: @mplungjan:CrystalBallPredicter? wats it...post me a link...

Comment: @Shankar - it is in development. I cannot predict when it will be available ;) Sorry - it was actually meant as a joke

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to make an AJAX call to your server-side code after the user clicked *OK* or *Cancel*.

This means you cannot return the status from your C# function.